# Magento 2.1.10: How to override Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager

Tags: magento2, overrides, session

I'm looking for solution for override.

> Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager

I use the usually way (preference in di.xml), but no hope.

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager" type="Gssi\FixEmptyCart\Session\SessionManager" />
</config>
```

> SessionManager.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento session manager
 *
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Gssi\FixEmptyCart\Session;

/**
 * Session Manager
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class SessionManager extends \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager
{
    public function regenerateId()
    {
        var_dump('1234'); exit;
        if (headers_sent()) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($this->isSessionExists()) {
            $oldSessionId = session_id();            
            session_regenerate_id();   //regen the session
            $new_session_id = session_id();

            $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;

            // Set destroy timestamp
            $_SESSION['destroyed'] = time();

            // Write and close current session;
            session_commit();
            $oldSession = $_SESSION;   //called after destroy - see destroy!
            // Start session with new session ID
            session_id($new_session_id);
            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
            session_start();
            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
            $_SESSION = $oldSession;
            // New session does not need them
            unset($_SESSION['destroyed']);
            unset($_SESSION['new_session_id']);  
        } else {
            session_start();
        }
        $this->storage->init(isset($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION : []);

        if ($this->sessionConfig->getUseCookies()) {
            $this->clearSubDomainSessionCookie();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function start()
    {
        if (!$this->isSessionExists()) {
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('session_start');

            try {
                $this->appState->getAreaCode();
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException(
                    new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(
                        'Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.'
                    ),
                    $e
                );
            }

            // Need to apply the config options so they can be ready by session_start
            $this->initIniOptions();
            $this->registerSaveHandler();
            if (isset($_SESSION['new_session_id'])) {
             // Not fully expired yet. Could be lost cookie by unstable network.
             session_commit();
             session_id($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
             }
            // potential custom logic for session id (ex. switching between hosts)
            $this->setSessionId($this->sidResolver->getSid($this));
            session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION['destroyed'])) {
               if ($_SESSION['destroyed'] < time()-300) {
                   $this->destroy(['clear_storage' => true]);

               }
            }
            $this->validator->validate($this);

            register_shutdown_function([$this, 'writeClose']);

            $this->_addHost();
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('session_start');
        }
        $this->storage->init(isset($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION : []);
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

I've also clear cache, enable this module, setup upgrade ..
Please help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Because many child classes extend **Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager**

Magento used subclass of **Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager** instead of **Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager** such as

- \Magento\Company\Model\Authorization\Session
- \Magento\Customer\Model\Session

And objectManager Create Subclass not **Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager**, You can try to override **Magento\Customer\Model\Session**.

in that bug, you should apply the path instead of trying to fix.

Link reference path file: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12362#issuecomment-416065934

Comment: thanks, i'll try it later :)
they override vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Index/Index.php

Comment: Magento Override that controller too.

Answer (score 0):

So i've found the solution
My solution is based on Git command:
First, you create 2 .patch file in `patches` folder in magento root folder.
For example: My project named "magento_project". So the .patch file should be created in "htdocs/magento_project/patches/sessionmanager.patch"
Here is my patch file i've created for magento 2.1.10 to fix "empty cart" issue ( check the link to know how to fix "empty cart" issue)
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12362

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_project\patches\sessionmanager.patch

```
--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
@@ -468,12 +468,23 @@
         if ($this->isSessionExists()) {
-            $oldSessionId = session_id();
-            session_regenerate_id();
-            $newSessionId = session_id();
-            session_id($oldSessionIds);
-            session_destroy();
-
-            $oldSession = $_SESSION;
-            session_id($newSessionId);
-            session_start();
-            $_SESSION = $oldSession;
+            $oldSessionId = session_id();
+            session_regenerate_id();   //regen the session
+            $new_session_id = session_id();
+
+            $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;
+
+            // Set destroy timestamp
+            $_SESSION['destroyed'] = time();
+
+            // Write and close current session;
+            session_commit();
+            $oldSession = $_SESSION;   //called after destroy - see destroy!
+            // Start session with new session ID
+            session_id($new_session_id);
+            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
+            session_start();
+            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
+            $_SESSION = $oldSession;
+            // New session does not need them
+            unset($_SESSION['destroyed']);
+            unset($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
         } else {
\ No newline at end of file
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_project\patches\sessionmanager2.patch

```
--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
@@ -185,7 +185,19 @@
             $this->registerSaveHandler();

-            // potential custom logic for session id (ex. switching between hosts)
-            $this->setSessionId($this->sidResolver->getSid($this));
-            session_start();
-            $this->validator->validate($this);
+            if (isset($_SESSION['new_session_id'])) {
+             // Not fully expired yet. Could be lost cookie by unstable network.
+             session_commit();
+             session_id($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
+             }
+            // potential custom logic for session id (ex. switching between hosts)
+            $this->setSessionId($this->sidResolver->getSid($this));
+            session_start();
+            if (isset($_SESSION['destroyed'])) {
+               if ($_SESSION['destroyed'] < time()-300) {
+                   $this->destroy(['clear_storage' => true]);
+
+               }
+            }
+            $this->validator->validate($this);
+

             register_shutdown_function([$this, 'writeClose']);
\ No newline at end of file
```

Okay, the reason i created 2 file because when i put them in one file, it will cause an error `patch fragment without header` which i still dont know how to fix.
After create this 2 patch file, open command line in your magento root folder, which in mine case is "magento_project".
And type `git apply patches/sessionmanager.patch` and `git apply patches/sessionmanager2.patch`.

If you got error when running this command, and it say something about line 468 and line 185, it highly because of your `SessionManager.php` in your project is different than mine.
Please check again in patch file and change so it look like `SessionManager.php` in your project.
Oh, and dont forget to check the `white space` in patch file. **Its really important**. The `white space` of patch file is always = `white space` in `SessionManager.php` +1, accept for the line which have + and - at the beginning of the line.

That's it. Thanks for reading. Hope it help some one :)
Gonna update if i know something else